# Go error - expected ';', found 'package' in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, go

When trying to create a new golang program, I'm getting the error - **expected ';', found 'package'**  in Visual Studio.

Go Version -1.14

[image]

Edit:
The error appears even after saving the file.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

the main file seems unsaved, try to save it

Comment: Even after saving the error appears.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting the Visual studio after saving the file temporarily fix the problem.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/3082